# GWTP ViewWithUiHandlers: uiHandlers are not set. Did you call getUiHandlers() from your view's constructor? in PresenterWidget

Tags: gwt, gwtp, gwt-platform

I have problem that I do not understand. I think I've done what I supposed to do, but it dosnt work.

I cannot executed presenter methods from view using ui handlers. Error says that I did not set ui handlers but I did:

```
@Inject
FileUploaderPresenter(EventBus eventBus, MyView view, PlaceManager placeManager) {
   super(eventBus, view);
   getView().setUiHandlers(this);
   this.placeManager = placeManager;
}
```

and

```
public FileUploaderView() {
   super();
   this.getUiHandlers();
   this.initWidget(uploader);
}
```

But I am getting an error:

```
com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.ViewWithUiHandlers
SEVERE: uiHandlers are not set.  Did you call getUiHandlers() from your view's constructor?
```

For sure I will post all my classes related:

```
public class FileUploaderModule extends AbstractPresenterModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindSingletonPresenterWidget(FileUploaderPresenter.class, FileUploaderPresenter.MyView.class, FileUploaderView.class);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class FileUploaderPresenter extends PresenterWidget<FileUploaderPresenter.MyView> implements FileUploaderUiHandlers {
    interface MyView extends View, HasUiHandlers<FileUploaderUiHandlers> {
    }

    PlaceManager placeManager;

    @Inject
    FileUploaderPresenter(EventBus eventBus, MyView view, PlaceManager placeManager) {
    super(eventBus, view);
        getView().setUiHandlers(this);
    this.placeManager = placeManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBind() {
    super.onBind();
    }

    @Override
    public void onOk() {
    Routing.Redirect.toLoginPage(placeManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUnauthorized() {
    Routing.Redirect.toLoginPage(placeManager);
    }

}
```

---

```
interface FileUploaderUiHandlers extends UiHandlers {
    void onUnauthorized();

    void onOk();

}
```

---

```
public class FileUploaderView extends ViewWithUiHandlers<FileUploaderUiHandlers> implements FileUploaderPresenter.MyView {

    MaterialFileUploader uploader = new MaterialFileUploader();

    public FileUploaderView() {
        super();
        this.getUiHandlers();
        this.initWidget(uploader);
        MaterialUploadLabel label = new MaterialUploadLabel();
        label.setTitle("Put Your's files here and here");
        label.setDescription("Some description here");
        uploader.add(label);
        uploader.setMaxFileSize(10000000);
        uploader.setUrl(ServiceRouting.FULL_SERVICE +           ServiceRouting.FileService.upload);
    addHandlers();
    }

    private void addHandlers() {
    uploader.addUnauthorizedHandler(new UnauthorizedHandler<UploadFile>() {
        @Override
        public void onUnauthorized(UnauthorizedEvent<UploadFile> event) {
        GWT.log("UnauthorizedEvent (" + event.getTarget().getName() + " | " + event.getResponse().getCode() + " | " + event.getResponse().getMessage() + "|" + event.getResponse().getBody()
            + ")");
        MaterialToast.fireToast("Redirect to login page");
        getUiHandlers().onUnauthorized();
        }
    });
}
```

I instantialize this widget with: `FileUploaderView()`

Is this error happens, cause I don't use uiBinder?
This is my first **PresenterWidget**. Maybe it should be done differently from standard Presenter. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I've figure it out on my own.

The problem is that This Presenter/View pair is a widget. So it should be instantialize with slot mechanism of gwtp. And to do this we use bind method with Presenter class parameter (not view like I was doing).

```
@Inject UploaderPresenter fileUploaderPresenter;

@Override
protected void onBind() {
    super.onBind();
    setInSlot(SLOT_FILE_UPLOAD, fileUploaderPresenter);
}
```

Here is documentation:

http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/tutorials/tutorial-part2.html

sections:

- Binding the PresenterWidget
- Set in slot
- Bind Slot

http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/core/presenters/

Comment: onReset is definitely the wrong place. Like the wrongest place possible. onBind is called once - think about using that one

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just let's trace the steps from your code:

This is the constructor of your presenter. `MyView view` injected here WAS ALREADY CREATED here to be passed to your constructor.

```
 @Inject
FileUploaderPresenter(EventBus eventBus, MyView view, PlaceManager placeManager) {
   super(eventBus, view);
   getView().setUiHandlers(this)
```

which means

```
public FileUploaderView() {
   super();
   this.getUiHandlers();
   this.initWidget(uploader);
}
```

is called BEFORE presenter contructor. So you call this.getUiHandlers() before you set them in Presenter's constructor.

Move the call to some kind of @UiHandler

Comment: But @UiHandler if for Fields that correspond to UiBinder. And I don't use binder. Which call do You mean exacly?

Comment: Ok, then access getUiHandlers() from your event handlers

Comment: This change nothing. I cannot delegate execution to Presenter, cause `getUiHandlers()` is null. Are You aware that this is `PresenterWidget`? Not regular `Presenter`.

Comment: OK, I'm recreating your set of files on my machine, meanwhile - can you trace it with the log statements? Log something after setUiHandlers and check does it happen before UnauthorizedEvent ? Also remove ' this.getUiHandlers();' from the FileUploaderView() it will obviously never work.

Comment: Ok. I've done this. This is PresenterWidget, so it must be added to ui using Slot mechanism using `bindSlot` method.